# Issue with basic SQLite database access in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a database called "default.db" and it is a working database [I can access it through the SQLite utilities and see the tables inside].

I have this code for accessing the database:

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite

conn = sqlite.connect("default.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

#retrieve all database data

cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name;")
print "fetch all"
cur.fetchall()

print "printing"
print cur
print conn
for i in cur:
    print "item"
    print i
```

The output is:

```
fetch all
printing
<pysqlite2.dbapi2.Cursor object at 0xb74a2de0>
<pysqlite2.dbapi2.Connection object at 0xb74713d8>
done
```

But if I run the commands individually I get this result from the code:

```
>>> cur.fetchall()
[(u'cards',), (u'data_for_fact',), (u'fact_views',), (u'fact_views_for_card_type',), (u'facts',), (u'global_variables',), (u'log',), (u'sqlite_sequence',), (u'tags',), (u'tags_for_card',)]
```

My question is: How can I fix this, and what is going wrong? I'm not getting any errors connecting to the db [its not reporting any].

edit: I tried saving the fetchall to an variable, but the variable prints out as []. (Empty)

Comment: cur.fetchall() prints out a list but you did not tell it to print anything. That is a clue that cur.fetchall() returns a value and that your code is NOT assigning that value to a variable. Therefore, you are throwing away the results of the query. Pay attention to documentation, both function arguments AND function results.

Comment: I was hoping that it would print out in the script, thats why I didn't assign it a value. It was an later add on to the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the database didn't exist where it was expected to. In turn, it just created an empty file and database.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should iterate over `cur.fetchall()` not the `cur` -> cursor itself.

It should be like;

```
for i in cur.fetchall():
    print "item"
    print i
```

And you should also drop the previous `cur.fetcall()` command.

Comment: Your suggestion does not print anything.

Comment: You can only run fetchall once on the same cursor, so you have to makesure the previous cur.fetchall() is removed.

Comment: The first cur.fetchall() drains the iterator.  Remove the first one or reexecute the select before this one and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read the [DBAPI docs](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). But basically, the cursor is not iterable itself. The methods, such as `fetchall` return lists as your last sample shows. Your first example returns the list but is discarded (not assigned).

From that doc, fetchall does:

> Fetch all (remaining) rows of a query
>   result, returning them as a sequence
>   of sequences (e.g. a list of tuples).
>   Note that the cursor's arraysize
>   attribute can affect theperformance of
>   this operation.

Comment: Iterable cursors are optional, but nevertheless SQLite supports them.

Comment: @cristian The evidence show here would suggest that it doesn't. ;-)

Comment: The first `cur.fetchall()` drains the iterator.  `for i in cur` works if you comment the `fetchall` out.

Comment: Aha. I didn't see that in the PEP. But I think that having the cursor and the fetchall, two different things, affecting each other like that is non-obvious and a questionable design.

Answer (score 0):

`cur.fetchall()` retrieves all the lines, but you don't save them in a variable.  Change to `print cur.fetchall()` and drop everything after it in your script, or comment the `fetchall` out and the iterator will work:

### Example

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute('create table  a(a,b,c,d)')
cur.execute('insert into a values(1,2,3,4)')
cur.execute('insert into a values(2,3,4,5)')
cur.execute('insert into a values(3,4,5,6)')
cur.execute('insert into a values(4,5,6,7)')
cur.execute('select * from a')
for i in cur:
    print i
```

#### Output

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 4, 5)
(3, 4, 5, 6)
(4, 5, 6, 7)
```